# got 'invalid_grant' in oauth2 SignedJwtAssertionCredentials

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, oauth2client

I am trying to make an oauth2 access_token in a server-to-server JSON API scenario. But it failed with invalid_grant error, please help.

```
from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials

KEY_FILE = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx-privatekey.p12'

with open(KEY_FILE, 'r') as fd:
    key = fd.read()

SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = 'xxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com'

credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL, key,
      scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/datastore https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
      token_uri='https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token')


assertion = credentials._generate_assertion()

h = httplib2.Http()
credentials._do_refresh_request(h.request)
```

and I got

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/pahud/Projects/oauth2client/x.py", line 24, in <module>
    credentials._do_refresh_request(h.request)
  File "/Users/pahud/Projects/oauth2client/oauth2client/client.py", line 710, in _do_refresh_request
    raise AccessTokenRefreshError(error_msg)
oauth2client.client.AccessTokenRefreshError: invalid_grant
[Finished in 0.7s with exit code 1]
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGGYx.png

Comment: The email scope needs to start with "https" (not "http"). Does that resolve the issue?

Comment: @EdDavisson no, still got invalid_grant  :(

Comment: Also unsynch. time on machine can give similar error.

Answer (score 12):

I fixed it.

```
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = 'xxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com'
```

the above is client ID not Email, I fixed this and it's working now.

Comment: In my case I was using my account login email rather than the service account email address you get when you create a new client Id from the credentials sections in the Google Developers Console

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem.

To solve the problem, you need to notice the following elements:

1. Did you use client_secrets.json in your program? If yes, check whether the name is the same as that in your current directory.
2. The "`client_email` " or the "`SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL`" is not your personal email or the client id. It is "client id's email". You can check that email in https://console.developers.google.com/project/ `==>credentials==>Service account==>email address`.

   Basically, if your client id is:`<clientid>.apps.googleusercontent.com`

   You client email here would be:`<clientid>@developer.gserviceaccount.com`

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was with the .boto file. Try to configure it again with the credentials from the Service account.

For the ones using fallback: `gcs_oauth2_boto_plugin.SetFallbackClientIdAndSecret(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET)`

use for the fallback any "Client ID for native application". This is not necessary as its said in: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gspythonlibrary

but i couldn't find other way, it was throwing errors without it.