# domain-wide authority SignedJwtAssertionCredentials access_denied

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-api

I have a problem with SignedJwtAssertionCredentials .
The problem has already been reported in this post: [got 'invalid_grant' in oauth2 SignedJwtAssertionCredentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23918443/got-invalid-grant-in-oauth2-signedjwtassertioncredentials)
but that solution didn't work for me.
So briefly here is my code:

```
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = 'xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com'
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PEM_FILE_PATH = 'privatekey.pem'
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user']

def get_drive_service_for_user(user_email):
    f = file(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PEM_FILE_PATH, 'rb')
    key = f.read()
    f.close()

    credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL, 
        key,
        scope=SCOPES, 
        sub=user_email)
    http = httplib2.Http()
    http = credentials.authorize(http)

    return build('drive', 'v2', http=http)
```

This is the log:

```
Refreshing access_token
I 09:08:54.911 Failed to retrieve access token: {
"error" : "access_denied",
"error_description" : "Requested client not authorized."
}
E 09:08:54.911 access_denied
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-   
2.3/webapp2.py", line 1511, in __call__
rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-
2.3/webapp2.py", line 1505, in __call__
rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-  
2.3/webapp2.py", line 1253, in default_dispatcher
return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-
2.3/webapp2.py", line 1077, in __call__
return handler.dispatch()
File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-
2.3/webapp2.py", line 547, in dispatch
return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-
2.3/webapp2.py", line 545, in dispatch
return method(*args, **kwargs)
File "/base/data/home/apps/s~docs-script/1.378398783184725654/source/handlers.py", line 15, in   
get
f_list = service.get_ousiders_files()
File "/base/data/home/apps/s~docs-script/1.378398783184725654/source/service.py", line 10, in 
get_ousiders_files
service = get_drive_service_for_user('fat.controller@steam2.com')
File "/base/data/home/apps/s~docs-script/1.378398783184725654/source/auth.py", line 102, in 
get_drive_service_for_user
return build('drive', 'v2', http=authorized_http)
File "/base/data/home/apps/s~docs-script/1.378398783184725654/apiclient/discovery.py", line 175, 
in build
resp, content = http.request(requested_url)
File "/base/data/home/apps/s~docs-script/1.378398783184725654/oauth2client/util.py", line 132, in 
positional_wrapper
return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
File "/base/data/home/apps/s~docs-script/1.378398783184725654/oauth2client/client.py", line 475, 
in new_request
self._refresh(request_orig)
File "/base/data/home/apps/s~docs-script/1.378398783184725654/oauth2client/client.py", line 653, 
in _refresh
self._do_refresh_request(http_request)
File "/base/data/home/apps/s~docs-script/1.378398783184725654/oauth2client/client.py", line 710, 
in _do_refresh_request
raise AccessTokenRefreshError(error_msg)

AccessTokenRefreshError: access_denied
```

I followed this guide to setup all the domain-wide authorization: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation#delegate_domain-wide_authority_to_your_service_account

Thanks for the help

Comment: Are you sure you added all those scopes in the "Manage third party OAuth Client access" AND have those APIs enabled on the Cloud Console?

Comment: I am sorry to answer only now, apparently it was a domain problem, running the same code on another domain worked fine. Thank you anyway

Comment: What was the domain problem?